# I need to generate a series of numbers as follows: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3. Is there an easy way to do this?

Tags: excel, numbers, row, series, fill

I am grateful if you can suggest something in Excel because I am not a skilled user of R

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in one cell. The easy solution is to use 2 columns.

Answer (score 3):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)+(MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3)+1)/10
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you want the series in a single cell and have **Excel 365**, then enter:

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(20),TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,ROUNDUP(x/3,0)+(MOD(x-1,3)+1)/10))
```

somewhere on the sheet

[image]

*(The 20 in the formula defines the number of items generated.)*

Comment: I like it - very nice

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tag VBA but you also mentioned both Excel & R so i'm assuming you may be open to VBA.

Try a UDF which can be called right from the sheet. This will repeat the pattern you provided from `1 to Target` where target is the input of the function.

```
Public Function REPT_CUSTOM(Target As Long) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

For i = 1 To Target
    For x = 1 To 3   
        REPT_CUSTOM = REPT_CUSTOM & ", " & i & "." & x
    Next x
Next i

REPT_CUSTOM = Mid(REPT_CUSTOM, 3)

End Function
```

---

Sample of inputs/outputs

[image]